# Make ocean monument spawn at absolute Y height

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-data-packs

How do I change the absolute spawn height of the ocean monument?

It seems to already have an absolute height (always being two blocks under the surface), but in my datapack that makes oceans deeper, the vanilla height results in long pillars extending to the seafloor. How do I change this vanilla absolute height?

Comment: I'm not sure, but I *think* you need to fiddle around with [these settings](https://minecraft.fandom.com/wiki/Custom_structure)?

Comment: I would like to do this with the vanilla structure rather than a custom one. However, it does not seem to support the absolute height tag